# dismiss button in the pop up does not work after first time

Tags: android

I have built an app which launches the camera and when image is clicked it is displayed in the popup window.Pop window has two buttons dismiss and reload.When the image is displayed in the popup button for the first time dismiss button works but i reload the camera and click the image dismiss button does not work
here is the code i used for popup

```
    private void initiatePopupWindow() {
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
    imageView = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
    try {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout,500, 500, true);
                pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            }
        }, 100);


        Button close = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button reload = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button2);


        reload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View popupView) {
                openCamera();
            }
        });
        close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View popupView) {
                pwindo.dismiss();
            }
        });


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
   public void openCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);


}
```

Comment: ` openCamera();` can you show this?

Comment: Dismiss popwindow when you tap on `reload` button `pwindo.dismiss();`

Comment: i have added openCamera